# Would prefixing the word "get" or "set" for method names in controller ran automatically without invoking?

Tags: controller

i am just getting suspicious that prefixing the word "get" or "set" before method names in controller run automatically without invoking? Experts please clarify?

Answer (score 3):

The methods are run by the Visualforce page rendering system automatically when the page is rendered if they are to be displayed on the page. If you [look at the guide here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_get_request.htm) on the order of execution for Visualforce page get requests it give you some more details about the order in which items are executed in order to help set the required values on the page.

Comment: Unless, of course, they are private.